# Failed to activate virtualenv with pyenv

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv, pyenv

I run:

```
pyenv activate new_app
```

And I get:

```
Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/59-Start-a-flask-project-from-zero-building-api-rest.html

Other info:

```
bash-3.2$ python --version
Python 3.6.0

bash-3.2$ pyenv version
3.6.0 (set by /Users/me/Projects/flask_api/.python-version)

bash-3.2$ pwd
/Users/me/Projects/flask_api

bash-3.2$ pyenv versions
  system
  3.5.1
  3.5.1/envs/my_env_3_5_1
* 3.6.0 (set by /Users/me/Projects/flask_api/.python-version)
  3.6.0/envs/new_app
  flask_app
  my_env_3_5_1
  new_app

bash-3.2$ virtualenv --version
15.1.0

bash-3.2$ pyenv virtualenvs
3.5.1/envs/my_env_3_5_1 (created from /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1)
  3.6.0/envs/new_app (created from /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0)
  flask_app (created from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7)
  my_env_3_5_1 (created from /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1)
  new_app (created from /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0)
```

I recently made my `.bash_profile` it contains:

```
bash-3.2$ cat ~/.bash_profile 
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
exec "$SHELL"
if which pyenv-virtualenv-init > /dev/null; then eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"; fi
```

What should I do to properly start virtualenv?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

That

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

should be in `.bashrc`, not `.bash_profile`. The latter is executed only by *login* shells, the former by all interactive shells.

Comment: work perfectly. Note: if you dont have .bashrc directory to make a one to execute this command

Comment: @phd: where `.bashrc ` should be placed?

Comment: In `~`, i.e. `$HOME`.

Comment: This has all changed in pyenv 2.0.  It has become quite frustrating now.

Comment: When I try with pyenv 2.0, it said `pyenv: no such command 'virtualenv-init'`

Answer (score 79):

Within `~/.zshrc` file:

```bash
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1

eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Sadly the `eval` lines alone (as mentioned in the pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv instructions) did not work for me.

Comment: Also check out my zsh prompt gist so that you can style your prompt without oh_my_zsh https://gist.github.com/aiqc/e55bfbf6b41d199015f79b9fcd7a46b3

Comment: The double init call was necessary for me too, +1.

Comment: Only this answer worked for me on macOS Monterey, thank you @Kalanos !

Comment: This worked for me. I had to include all 5 lines in my ~/.bashrc file, not just the 3 recommended in pyenv instructions.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to some sort of an explanation? This set of commands worked out for me, but I still have no idea why.

Comment: There isn't even a `~/.pyenv/bin` in my install, it's `~/.pyenv/shims` for me.

Comment: this worked in .bash_profile for me

Comment: This worked for me on mac os Ventura 13.01.

Answer (score 43):

1. Add the lines below to your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zprofile`

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"  
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

2. Restart shell or run the command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

### Note:

If you are using **zsh shell** (default for **macOS Catalina** and/or **Big Sur**) you have to use `~/.zprofile` file rather than `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: thank you! this saved me.. just upgraded to big sur and ran into this

Answer (score 9):

For me the below fixed my problem. I am using MacBook Pro
thanks @Kalanos

```
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

### For mac users!

**Make sure you have installed pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv using brew**

If you're default shell is set to bash, add the following lines to your **.bashrc** by opening shell and enter,

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

then add :

```
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

then press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to save changes!