# pyenv: failed to activate virtualenv - settings not read from .profile at login

Tags: bash, virtualenv, pyenv, .profile

This is a known topic, almost similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577194/failed-to-activate-virtualenv-with-pyenv).

However - why am I having the pyenv settings passed in ok from .profile at login **only up to** the virtualenv string.

```
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
  eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

After login, the above portion is read (pyenv is active in terminal) but not virtualenv. Manual activation of the venv produces the well-known error message.

```
$pyenv activate venv_name

Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.
```

I **can** solve this by explicitly sourcing *.profile* - then it works fine.
But why would *.profile* not be read or interpreted at once at login?

Modifying *.bashrc* takes **no** effect. Seems like it's not being read. But *.profile* is.
Global python is system (2.7).

Take care

Comment: Are you *sure* the first part is being evaluated at shell startup? e.g. that the `pyenv` function has been created, and you're not just running the `pyenv` executable from the path? When you run `type pyenv`, does it show you a path, or the definition of a pyenv function?

Comment: Yes, `type pyenv` returns `pyenv is a shell function`. And - if I masked the relevant part in _.profile_ pyenv'd not be called in terminal.

Comment: Followup: right - at login `type pyenv` returns a path down in the home dir, where the executable is. But if I masked the relevant part in _.profile_ pyenv'd not be called at all in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try pyenv init --path instead of pyenv init - and again putting it in bashrc.